# Finding parameters values of growth function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
 Number of days before vaccination  (x)     bacteria count (1000 pieces) (y) 
            1                                        112 
            2                                        148 
            3                                        241 
            4                                        363 
            5                                        585
```

I Need to find 2 things 
first calculate with growth function third day count and I have been counted.
=GROWTH(I3:I4;H3:H4;H5)

But I need to calculate parameters of growth function( =.^)

So how to calculate a and b? I tried to use excel solver but i didn't solve

Comment: Have you tried to fit the `LOG()` of the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [LOGEST](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/logest-function-f27462d8-3657-4030-866b-a272c1d18b4b?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60099&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) is designed for what you want:

> the LOGEST function calculates an exponential curve that fits your
>   data and returns an array of values that describes the curve. Because
>   this function returns an array of values, it must be entered as an
>   array formula.

Note that there is a difference in how the equation is expressed on an `x-y` chart with an exponential trendline, and by the function.  On the chart, `m` is expressed as a power of `e`, so to convert the value returned by the formula to be the same as what is seen on the chart, you would do something like:

```
=LN(INDEX(LOGEST(known_y,known_x),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with an exponentional growth, you want to describe. The basic way to handle this, is to take the logarythm of the whole thing, and apply linear regression on that, using the `Linest()` function.